# What is the best way to allow my SaaS customers to view only their AWS S3 objects over the public internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I could keep my AWS S3 account private and send files from AWS to users browsers via my servers but I'd prefer to allow the user to directly access the resource over AWS' S3 public URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the S3 bucket private. [Generate pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for your customers whenever they attempt to access an object. Your server will just need to run a small piece of code to return the URL to the customer, and all the download traffic is still handled by S3 directly.